# Calling Different Functions tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to call different functions based on the inputted text in a Tkinter program.

```
root=Tk()
tex=Text(root)
tex.pack(side='right')
inputfield = Entry(root)
inputfield.pack(side='bottom')
text = inputfield.get()
if 'weather:' in text:
    inputfield.bind('<Return>', lambda _: weather())
if 'open:' in text:
     inputfield.bind('<Return>', lambda _: program())

root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to make it so if the inputted text contains `weather:` then it will call the `weather()` function. But if the inputted text contains `open:` then it opens the `program()` function. However I cannot figure it out. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are retrieving the text of the Entry before the mainloop. Instead of that, you should check the content inside the callback function:

```
def callback(event):
    text = inputfield.get()
    if 'weather:' in text:
        weather()
    if 'open:' in text:
        program()

# ...
inputfield.bind('<Return>', callback)
```

Besides, if you bind two times the `<Return>`event, the second binding will override the previous one ([unless you pass `"+"` as the third argument](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.bind-method)). However, with only one callback you have enough to control both scenarios.